# ImportError: cannot import name 'hf_hub_download' from 'huggingface_hub'

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, conda

### Problem

I need a conda environment for [DeepLabCut](https://deeplabcut.github.io/DeepLabCut/README.html), I setted it up and I open python console, but I cannot import `from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download`.

### Scenario

Here below there is an example of my console output

```
(base) user@macbook ~ % conda activate TEST_ENV                                                 
(TEST_ENV) user@macbook ~ % python
Python 3.9.18 (main, Sep 11 2023, 08:38:23) 
[Clang 14.0.6 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import huggingface_hub
>>> from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'hf_hub_download' from 'huggingface_hub' (/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/TEST_ENV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/__init__.py)
>>>
```

The strange fact is that I can import the parent module with `huggingface_hub`, so this error comes out only when I try to import its child module called `hf_hub_download`

### Also tried

to reinstall anaconda, launch `conda clean --all`, change environment

Thanks so much for the attention payed.